# defineProperty on Backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If i want to add a custom property to my backbone model, is this the best was to do this? Is there a better way or a completely different approach to the functionality i want to achieve?

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   defaults:{
    monthly_amount: 100
   },

   initialize: function(model, options){

     var m = this;

     Object.defineProperty(this,"yearly_amount",{
       get: function() {
                         return (m.get("monthly_amount") * 12);
                       },
       set: function(value) {
                         m.set("monthly_amount", (value/12) );
                       }
     });

   }
});
```

Thanks!

Edit: The property is just "virtual", i do not want it to be within the model attributes when saving the model to the server.

Comment: Would just overriding the save method to only include the fields you want be an option? http://jsfiddle.net/hEN88/1/

Comment: Not really, because yearly_amount would not always be in the correct relation to monthly_amount if i add it as a seperate attribute and just exclude it in the save method.

Comment: When I want a transient field in a model I just create a field for the object itself. Then I append what I need during runtime in this field and create funtions do deal with it instead of calling set/get of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the general problem here is often referred to as "computed properties" and there are plugins for backbone that provide this (see below). Backbone uses `get/set` method calling style as opposed to `defineProperty` style so your approach would make the value computation not transparent to views and thus be a pretty strong departure from backbone's design. A plugin that maintains the proper `get/set` and `change` interfaces is going to maintain the basic Model API so the view doesn't have to treat this particular model attribute differently.

See also the [backbone wiki of plugins](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources).

Available plugins:

- [Backbone.ModelMorph](https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.ModelMorph)
- [Backbone.ComputedModel](https://github.com/steve8708/Backbone.ComputedModel)
- [Backbone.Spark](https://github.com/phdesign/Backbone.Spark)
- [Backbone.ComputedFields](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/backbone-computedfields)

Answer (score 0):

When you set your property to defaults oject, it goes to attributes, but it doesn't suit us.
Since Backbone model is an regular object, you can access to it's properties as to objects properties:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}),
    model = new myModel();

model.monthly_amount = 50;
console.log(model.monthly_amount)
```

or create setter and getter like this:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    setMonthlyAmount: function (value) {
        this.monthly_amount = value;
    },

    getMonthlyAmount: function () {
        return this.monthly_amount;
    }

});

//access with getter/setter
var model = new myModel();

model.setMonthlyAmount(20);
var result = model.getMonthlyAmount();
console.log(result);
```

[Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUVu8/1/)